# Calculate all values of $\log(\sin z)$ for $z = \frac{2}{i}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate all values of $\log(\sin z)$ for $z = \frac{2}{i}$

Taking $\sin(\frac{2}{i})$ where $\sin{z}=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$, I got $\sin{(z)}=\frac{e^2-e^{-2}}{2i}$

Then taking $\log(z)=\ln\left|z\right|+i\operatorname{arg}z$

I've gotten to $$\log\left|\frac{e^2-e^{-2}}{2}\right|+i\operatorname{arg}\bigg(\frac{e^2-e^{-2}}{2i}+2\pi k\bigg)$$ using $2\pi\times k$ to show it's multivalued.

But I can't make any progress from here, I think the answer should be neater.

Comment: Where is $\frac{2}{i}$ coming from? The question asks for $z=2i$, so you can use the definition of the multivalued logarithm $\log z = \ln r + i (\theta + 2n\pi)$ where $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi]$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $z = re^{i\theta}$.

Comment: My apologies, the question is supposed to be 2/i. I have corrected it now.

Comment: That's not the correct position of  $2\pi\times k$